# Estoy desarrollando una app con Android Studio y SQLite, No puedo hacer una consulta individual

Tags: java, android, sqlite

soy un nuevo con Android Studio y SQLite y por ello estoy desarrollando una pequeña app de prueba de un simple registro. Y necesito implementar un método en el que haga una consulta a la base de datos que cree con SQLite, pero desafortunadamente no tengo un resultado favorable. Lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de indicar el nombre por medio de un "EditText", encuentre el dato registrado en la base de datos y rellene los campos de "apellidos" y "edad", pero no tengo éxito, si alguien es tan amable de ayudar se lo agradecería.

Logcat

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/xample.pruebab: Accessing hidden method Lcom/msic/qarth/PatchStore;->createDisableExceptionQarthFile(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Z (blacklist, JNI)
E/xample.pruebab: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pruebabd, PID: 10238
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT apellidos, edad FROM usuarios WHERE androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{4d3ddb7 VFED..CL. .F...... 371,154-1103,298 #7f0a01e6 app:id/editTextCINombre}=?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:948)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:559)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1335)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1206)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1374)
        at com.example.pruebabd.consultaIndividual.consultar(consultaIndividual.java:50)
        at com.example.pruebabd.consultaIndividual.onClick(consultaIndividual.java:33)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Clase: "consultaIndividual"

```
package com.example.pruebabd;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.pruebabd.utilidades.Utilidades;

public class consultaIndividual extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Crear los objetos del XML
    EditText eTNombre;
    EditText eTApellidos;
    EditText etEdad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta_individual);
        // Asignar las variables anteriormente creadas a los activitys del XML por "Id"
        eTNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCINombre);
        eTApellidos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCIApellidos);
        etEdad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCIEdad);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.imageButtonConsultar:
                consultar();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void consultar(){
        // Creamos un objeto nuevo de la clase "AdminSQLiteOpenHelper", para abrir la base de datos
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "usuarios", null, 1);
        // Se crea el objeto de la clase "SQLiteDataBase" para crear la conexión con la base de datos
        SQLiteDatabase BD = admin.getReadableDatabase();

        // Arreglo que busca por los parametros indicados
        String[] parametro = {eTNombre.getText().toString()};
        // Arreglo para indicar los campos a visualizar
        String[] campos = {"apellidos", "edad"};
        //try{
            // Con el objeto "cursor", consultar en la base de datos con el campo "eTnombre"
            Cursor cursor = BD.query("usuarios", campos, eTNombre+"=?", parametro, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            // Mostramos los campos
            eTApellidos.setText(cursor.getString(0));
            etEdad.setText(cursor.getInt(1));
            cursor.close();
        //} catch (Exception e){
        //}
    }
    public void regresar(View view){
        Intent AP = new Intent(this, PaginaPrincipal.class);
        startActivity(AP);
    }

    public void limpiar(){
        eTNombre.setText("");
        eTApellidos.setText("");
        etEdad.setText("");
    }
}
```

Clase: Usuario

```
package com.example.pruebabd.entidades;

public class Usuario {

    private Integer idUsuario;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private Integer edad;

    public Usuario(Integer idUsuario, String nombre, String apellidos, Integer edad) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public Integer getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(Integer idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public Integer getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(Integer edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}
```

Clase: Utilidades

```
package com.example.pruebabd.utilidades;

public class Utilidades {
    // Crear una base de datos en SQLite
    public static final String tablaUsuarios = "CREATE TABLE usuarios(" +
            " idUsuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
            " nombre TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " apellidos TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " edad INT NOT NULL)";
}
```

Clase: AdminSQLiteOpenHelper

```
package com.example.pruebabd;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.pruebabd.utilidades.Utilidades;

public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
        // Ejecuta la instrucción para crear la tabla: "usuarios", que se aloja en la clase "Utilidades"
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL(Utilidades.tablaUsuarios);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos, int versionAntigua, int versionNueva) {
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usuarios");
        onCreate(BaseDeDatos);
    }
}
```

---

Gracias a @Jorgesys y @Franqo Balsamo, por contribuir y ayudarme a resolver mis errores.
Agrego que todavía un detalle que ya pude resolver y la aplicación funciona como es debido.
Tenia pendiente estos errores del Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" y "Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x15"
```

Como pueden observar en el método consultar están las líneas de codigo que rellenan
los campos de "apellidos" y "edad" más específicamente
Línea Incorrecta

```
etEdad.setText(cursor.getInt(1));
```

A lo que puedo entender mi error fue, que el objeto de la clase "Cursor", buscaba un entero en vez de una cadena de texto.
La corrección fue la siguiente:

```
etEdad.setText(cursor.getString(1));
```

Una vez más agradezco a los que se tomaron el tiempo de ayudarme ¡GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema es que estás ejecutando mal la consulta:

```
Cursor cursor = BD.query("usuarios", campos, eTNombre+"=?", parametro, null, null, null);
```

`eTNombre` es el nombre de tu `EditText` por lo que jamás encontrará el nombre de tu campo. A lo que puedo entender, quieres parametrizar la consulta basándote en el valor del nombre. Por lo que, lo que quieres hacer sería esto:

```
Cursor cursor = BD.query("usuarios", campos, "nombre=?", parametro, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Gracias, estaba en un error como me comentaste. Tenia un error en mi consulta y el problema referente a: "no such column: eTNombre", se soluciono, pero sigo teniendo errores. Trabajare en ellos.

Comment: Si el problema a tu pregunta se solucionó, da por aceptada la pregunta. Si surgieron nuevos problemas, puedes hacer una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al LogCat, el error sucede inicialmente cuando llamas el onClick:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
> android:onClick

y se provoca al tratar de ejecutar una consulta incorrecta:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax
> error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT
> apellidos, edad FROM usuarios WHERE
> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{4d3ddb7 VFED..CL. .F......
> 371,154-1103,298 #7f0a01e6 app:id/editTextCINombre}=?, (OS error -
> 2:No such file or directory)

Estas usando la instancia del `EditText` `eTNombre` para definir una cadena:

```
 Cursor cursor = BD.query("usuarios", campos, eTNombre+"=?", parametro, null, null, null);
```

si lo que en realidad quieres es usar el campo "eTnombre", debes definir de esta forma tu consulta:

```
Cursor cursor = BD.query("usuarios", campos, "eTNombre=?", parametro, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda, pero no tuve éxito. Leyendo el Logcat con más detalle, me indica que la columna eTnombre no existe. `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: eTNombre (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT apellidos, edad FROM usuarios WHERE eTNombre=?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)´. ¿Parece que busca una columna de la base de datos?